# Rate limits for Dailymotion API

Tags: dailymotion-api

The Dailymotion API documentation indicates that some fields are rate limited (for example stream_h264_hd1080_url for video resource, see on http://www.dailymotion.com/doc/api/obj-video.html).

I could not find any information on this limits in their documentation or via google.

It just seems that the field return null most of the time, and works for a few minutes from time to time. I don't know if this limitation is per user-token or per-application.

Does anybody has information about it ?

Answer (score 1):

All stream_*_url fields are rate-limited to 50 calls per day. 
Upload is also limited to 4 per hour.

This field may return null when this quality level is not available or when the user providing the access token is not the owner of the video.

Comment: My experience is : 1) there is a limit which is not by day, as the field can return an URL several time, then null, then an URL again in a few minutes range. 2) there is a limit by video, as video A can return an URL several time, then null, and video B will still return URL if it has not been requested as much as for video A. Any documentation link on that ?